# Install TurboGears on windows xp

Tags: python, windows-xp, turbogears

I've been trying to get TurboGears installed on Windows by following [this](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/python-development-windows/) site.
I've installed virtualenv but when I execute the command "virtualenv --no-site-packages testproj", I get the following message:

```
New python executable in testproj\Scripts\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\virtualenv-script.py", line 8, in 
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.4.5', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.4.5-py2.6.egg\virtualenv.py", line 529, in main
    use_distribute=options.use_distribute)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.4.5-py2.6.egg\virtualenv.py", line 612, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.4.5-py2.6.egg\virtualenv.py", line 837, in install_python
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 621, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 830, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 14001] This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem
```

Can someone help me debug this ? If any one knows a better tutorial to install turbogears, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest asking at http://groups.google.com/group/turbogears/topics .

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the error. Apparently, virtualenv does not like it if folder names have spaces (eg Documents and Settings). It worked fine when my folder names had no spaces.